# How do I heal non-party members?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon, pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon

Sometimes, the client of a request or some character relevant to the story will accompany me into a dungeon. However, they aren't part of my "party", so I can't see their health or use items on them.

For whatever reason, they also don't have the natural healing over time that party members do.

Is there any way to heal these NPCs outside of waiting for them to faint and then reviving them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1.**
You can just face them and then throw a potion or oran berry at them.

**Method 2.**
Click on items tab. Select a potion or oran berry and press on eat option. Then press the -> arrow and then click A.

Your team member will automatically eat it.

Comment: Method 1 worked for me, however, I was not able to get Method 2 to work. Are you sure it works for non-team members?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Method 2 doesn't work for me either. There is no -> arrow and pressing `>` on the dpad doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can also try ↓ arrow.